# Converting of LED Strip WATTS & LUMENS value to 100mm length

Tags: light-fixture

How do we get the WATTS and LUMENS value of LED strip at 100mm length? For example a LED Strip is 35W/m and has a equivalent lumens of 3004lm/W.

Answer (score 3):

It's just simple math.

100mm=0.1m so 35W/m = 3.5 W/100mm

3004lm/W looks like a typo, frankly. So the resulting 3.5W * 3004lm/W = 10,514 lm is an error, but it would be correct if the numbers given were. Considering that 200lm/W is still pretty rare and expensive efficiency, I'll go with typo as the only likely explanation for reality. Well, that or "blatantly lying supplier with other reasons to have a poor reputation"

For strip lights 30.04 with a resulting 105 lm seems far more likely, albeit there are better ones. But not factor-of-10 better ones. Or 3004 lm/m so 300.4 lm for 0.1m so a believable 85 lm/W (pretty good for a strip light, which usually have poor heatsinks, so might still be too good to be true...)

Comment: Yeah, I'm seeing *max* 300 lumens per watt for these things.